# golang exec osascript not calling

Tags: go, exec

I wrote a command that sends a text, but it's not working, even though if I paste the command in it does. Is there some syntax error or thing i'm missing?

The printed command is:
`/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Messages"' -e 'set mybuddy to a reference to text chat id "iMessage;+;chatXXXXXXXXXX"' -e 'send "test" to mybuddy' -e 'end tell'`

my code is:

```
command := fmt.Sprintf("/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application \"Messages\"' -e 'set mybuddy to a reference to text chat id \"%s\"' -e 'send \"%s\" to mybuddy' -e 'end tell'", chatid, message)
fmt.Println(command)
exec.Command(command).Run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`Command` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command):

> The returned Cmd's Args field is constructed from the command name followed by the elements of arg, so arg should not include the command name itself. For example, Command("echo", "hello"). Args[0] is always name, not the possibly resolved Path.

So, you should do something like:

```
argChatID := fmt.Sprintf(`'set mybuddy to a reference to text chat id "%s"'`, chatid)
argMessage := fmt.Sprintf(`'send "%s" to mybuddy'`, message)

exec.Command("/usr/bin/osascript", "-e", `'tell application "Messages"'`, 
    "-e", argChatID, "-e", argMessage,  "-e", "'end tell'").Run()
```